# How do you run Code Analysis against a subset of files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

Currently I'm working on/in a project that doesn't have code analysis turned on.

What I'd like to do is just run CA against the files that I work with/touch before I check them in but there's some limitations:

- I don't have the option to turn it on for the project. Even if I did...
- The project is huge; CA takes an age to run, and the warnings are numerous. Picking out the files I touched from the list would be a needle in a haystack.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to run code rules through the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) (Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the tool).

*What I'd like to do is just run CA against the files that I work with/touch*

Concerning this first point, NDepend let's write code rules through LINQ queries, and one facility proposed is to [query the code diff](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Diff.aspx) between the current code version, and a previous version of the code (the baseline). Hence the user can write a code rule that focuses only on what has been changed between now and the baseline.

Around 200 default code rules are proposed, for example [Avoid making complex methods even more complex](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html). If we look at the LINQ code of this rule, we can see that first, it filters only methods where [CodeWasChanged](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ICompareContext~CodeWasChanged.html), to then detect the ones that were complex enough, and that became more complex. Method complexity is defined here through the popular code metric [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMethod~CyclomaticComplexity.html).

```
// <Name>Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)</Name>

warnif count > 0 
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where
  m.CodeWasChanged() // <-----

let oldCC = m.OlderVersion().CyclomaticComplexity
where oldCC > 6 && m.CyclomaticComplexity > oldCC 

select new { m,
    oldCC ,
    newCC = m.CyclomaticComplexity ,
    oldLoc = m.OlderVersion().NbLinesOfCode,
    newLoc = m.NbLinesOfCode,
}
```

All default or custom rules can be adapted to be restricted to code that has been refactored or code that has been introduced, since the baseline. The group of code rules *[Code Quality Regression](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html)* or *API Breaking Changes* contains these adapted code rules out-of-the-box.

Concerning the point *CA takes an age to run, and the warnings are numerous.* you can [try NDepend now](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx), and see that it won't make you wait. It'll take a few seconds to analyze your large code base and execute the 200 default rules (that can be customized easily since they are just C# LINQ queries).